# Combinatorial solution of a nonlinear algebraic equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider the System of algebraic equations

$X = X_0 + aYZ$

$Y = Y_0 + bXZ$

$Z = Z_0 + cXY$

with constants $X_0,Y_0,Z_0,a,b,c$, where $a,b,c<<1$ such that I can use an iterative Solutions in Terms of series Expansion in These small coefficients (convergence guaranteed).

This yields

$X = X_0 + a(Y_0+bXZ)Z_0 = X_0 +aY_0Z_0+abZ_0XZ$

after 1 Iteration, where I have, from combinatorial Point of view a sum over all tree graphs generated by this System of equations. The $X_0,Y_0,Z_0$ mark the end of a tree and every factor $a,b$ or $c$ corresponds to one branching in a tree. Therefore, the term $aYZ$ generates a branching (a) of type X and makes the branch X to a double-branch with one branch Y and another one Z. Similarily, $bXZ$ is a branching of type Y, where the branch Y continues to a double-branch with one branch X and another branch Z. If I would substitute the values $X_0,Y_0$ or $Z_0$ I mark the end of a tree, i.e. I mark that there are no further branchings on this branch. Finally, after further iterations I get the solution

$X = \sum_{Q \in Trees} \#Aut(Q) a^{n_X(Q)}b^{n_Y(Q)}c^{n_Y(Q)} X_0^{m_X(Q)} Y_0^{m_Y(Q)} Z_0^{m_Z(Q)}$.

Here, $n_i(Q)$ is the number of branchings of type $i$ occuring in $Q$, $m_i(Q)$ is the number of branches of sort $i$ that we can find at the end of the tree graph $Q$ and $\#Aut(Q)$ the number of occurences of graph $Q$ in this Expansion. For example (see above), for $n_X = 1,n_Y = n_Z = 0,m_X = 0, m_Y = m_Z = 1$ I have $\#Aut = 1$.

My question is: How to determine $\#Aut(Q)$ for a General tree? Is there some literature regarding this iterative Solutions in Terms of tree diagrams?

I guess that I have to consider every branching Point and determine how many times I can rearrange the branches without changing topology (say I have $p_\alpha$ possible interchangings of branches on branching Point $\alpha$). I will have something like $\#Aut(Q) = \prod_{\alpha \in Q}p_\alpha$, but is it right?